# How to compile youtube-api application

Tags: youtube-api

I am developing a custom Youtube video player. But I am not able to compile the program. I am missing something in Makefile. My program looks like

main.c

```
#include<gdata/services/youtube/gdata-youtube-service.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv[])
    {
     printf("Youtube Application\n");
     return 0;
    }
```

makefile

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs libgdata-google-1.2`  -lgdata-google-1.2 main.c -o youtube
```

When I compile, it is giving error like

> error: gdata/services/youtube/gdata-youtube-service.h: No such file or directory

Do I got to install some other packages ? Or, i need to include something in my Makefile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on Debian/Ubuntu? You probably want the `libgdata-dev` package.

```
$ apt-file search gdata/services/youtube/gdata-youtube-service.h
libgdata-dev: /usr/include/libgdata/gdata/services/youtube/gdata-youtube-service.h
```

Tried compiling it too, and tried using one of the methods declared in *gdata-youtube-service.h*

```
$ gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs libgdata` main.c -o yt
$ ./yt
Youtube Application
```